# How to sort an SQL query by the number of OR results

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am using VBA and SQLdeveloper to compare multiple keyword inputs against a database. I either search using all ANDs or all ORs, the ANDs has been working fine, but I want the OR's to return based on the number of successful comparisons. The code I have currently seems to return the results in a random fashion, rather than how I want it which is essentially relevancy. Here's an example of my code:

```
Dim sSQLOrder As String
sSQLOrder = " ORDER BY ( Title LIKE '%Title Keyword 1%' + Title LIKE '%Title 
Keyword 2%' + ...) DESC"
```

From my understanding, this should sort it, but doesn't. I've also tried sorting ASC vs DESC, which changes the order, but not in any productive way. Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: According to a comment, the code is in MS Access, so I fixed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

In any database, you should be able to use the ANSI standard `CASE` expression:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Title Keyword 1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
          CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Title Keyword 1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
          . . .
         ) DESC
```

Comment: I've tried this before and just tried it again, I get an error message saying: Error the filter applied to one or more fields was not valid.

Comment: @Anthrochange . . . The `ORDER BY` conditions are not usually referred to as a "filter".  Perhaps the problem is elsewhere in the query.

Comment: @Anthrochange - when you report error message for the purpose of getting help, you should report them EXACTLY as they are written. There are no "fields" in a relational database (certainly not in Oracle database); if you had that exact language in the error message, it may not have been an Oracle error.

Comment: @mathguy  that is the exact message I got, I don't think the problem is elsewhere as that is the only edit I made. The project I'm working on is on Access, I'm using VBA to code it, and calling sql to run the database search for full disclosure.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the SQL in Oracle SQL Developer first, then later define the string in VBA and execute as a PASS THROUGH query (ADODB connection).

If you're trying to use CASE WHEN in the Jet engine, it will fail. Native Access only allows "immediate if" IIF() functions--which you can still throw into the ORDER BY clause (it will just be messy since it's not as powerful as CASE WHEN).